# Correct Syntax for Swift5.7 (Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'block')

Tags: swift, scenekit

> on the line "let runBlock = SCNAction.run { (node) -> Void in
> block(node)
> }" I'm getting "Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'block' error", which seems to be caused by older syntax, wonder what should be the correct usage here

```
extension SCNAction {

class func waitForDurationThenRemoveFromParent(duration:TimeInterval) -> SCNAction {
    let wait = SCNAction.wait(duration: duration)
    let remove = SCNAction.removeFromParentNode()
    return SCNAction.sequence([wait,remove])
}

class func waitForDurationThenRunBlock(duration:TimeInterval, block: ((SCNNode?) -> Void) ) -> SCNAction {
    let wait = SCNAction.wait(duration: duration)
    let runBlock = SCNAction.run { (node) -> Void in
        block(node)
    }
    return SCNAction.sequence([wait,runBlock])
}

class func rotateByXForever(x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat, z:CGFloat, duration:TimeInterval) -> SCNAction {
    let rotate = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: x, y: y, z: z, duration: duration)
    return SCNAction.repeatForever(rotate)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the block escaping

```
class func waitForDurationThenRunBlock(duration:TimeInterval,  block: @escaping((SCNNode?) -> Void) ) -> SCNAction {
    let wait = SCNAction.wait(duration: duration)
    let runBlock = SCNAction.run { (node) -> Void in
        block(node)
    }
    return SCNAction.sequence([wait,runBlock])
}
```

Comment: thank you! it worked when I used  block: @escaping  here